# Does "SAM Local Invoke" support EFS?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I'm using Lambda to access EFS as described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-filesystem.html

The lambda function works fine when running in AWS, but it fails when using SAM with the "local invoke" command. The error is

```
2020-10-02T20:03:19.389Z        09b6f1b2-d80a-15e1-9531-f74182e95c1e    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
   "errorType":"Error",
   "errorMessage":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/efs/newfile.txt'",
   "code":"ENOENT",
   "errno":-2,
   "syscall":"open",
   "path":"/mnt/efs/newfile.txt",
   "stack":[
      "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/mnt/efs/newfile.txt'",
      "    at Object.openSync (fs.js:458:3)",
      "    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1355:35)",
      "    at WriteFile (/var/task/src/apis/permissions/isallowed.js:70:8)",
      "    at IsAllowedInPolicy (/var/task/src/apis/permissions/isallowed.js:52:5)",
      "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/src/apis/permissions/isallowed.js:16:28)",
      "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
   ]
}
```

Is "sam local invoke" supposed to work with EFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no.

I opened a support ticket with AWS and was told

> This is a limitation on the AWS SAM CLI and not your configuration.
> Therefore, I have taken the initiative to submit an internal feature
> request with our internal service team(specifically AWS SAM CLI
> service team) on your behalf and I have added your company name and
> voice to this request. At the moment, we would not be able to provide
> an estimate on if or when this feature will be supported. I would
> advise to check the AWS announcement page from time to time for future
> service updates. https://aws.amazon.com/new/

I also discovered that someone submitted a [feature request on GitHub as a workaround](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/2122).